# Are BIOS based key loggers undetectable?

Tags: bios, anti-virus, keylogger

tl;dr - **Is some one probably (>20% probability) sniffing my data?**

Reasons

1. After a fresh bios reset, hard disk format and windows install, my **key presses and snappy**
2. After about a month of usage, there is noticeable latency.  i press, it takes some time to register in the screen
3. **I do a bios reset, things are good**.  I do another hard disk format and os install, things get still snappier
4. It is NOT my perception regarding snappiness.  It really is noticeable, about half a second latency
5. I have done thorough virus scan using avast and malwarebyte amw.  **Nothing is detected**

If this was some hardware/bios issue - the bios reset should not have fixed the issue.

My conclusion
There might be some very specific virus residing either inside bios, or in header areas of hard disk.  And after os boots,it gets more payload.  Since this is very rare, no antivirus catches it.  Some one is trying to sniff into my data.

Question - **Is my conclusion reasonably probable (at-least 20 percent)? Am i way off the mark? Am i being paranoid without reason? Any way I can gather objective data to analyse from?**

Comment: It is very unlikely that you have a bios virus. Its more likely a hardware issue. I would start by testing with another keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

A bios or harddisk boot-loader virus with this effect is extremely unlikely.

A couple of far more likely other things to consider:

- Faulty keyboard. Disconnecting the keyboard for a few hours/overnight might clear this when it happens again. Or replace the keyboard.
- Your keyboard settings (key-pres time and/or key-repeat time) get changed by software. And on some motherboards this can also affect the keyboard timings in the BIOS, which will get cleared back to default by a bios reset.
  E.g: Some games temporarily mess with these settings to improve keyboard response during the game. Normally the game restores the original settings when you exit the game, but if the game crashes it doesn't restore this. And you are left with weird keyboard timing.
  If this is the case changing the keyboard settings in the Windows Control Panel should bring back normal response-times.
- Somebody with access to your computer installs software on your computer behind your back. Either malware (like a bad keylogger, you would not notice a good one!) or just some prank software to mess with your mind.
- It really is a virus/malware, which you get on the computer after some time of using it, after a fresh re-install. And somehow your anti-virus software misses it every time.

Just to be sure: When you get the problem again run another anti-virus product than your normal one. Many anti-virus vendors offer a free to use, one-time scan  from their web-site.
Chances that multiple anti-virus products will all overlook an infection is extremely small. If 2 or 3 different anti-virus programs agree that your computer is clean it is almost (100% certainty doesn't exist) guaranteed to be really clean.

Comment: Another possibility (which would not cause, but could compound) your issues could be a clogged CPU fan - after sitting off, it's cool, so it can click to full speed, but as it gets used it heats up, can't disipate the heat and underclock/slows down to protect the CPU, exacerbating other performance issues.